# How to implement async in DOTween?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await

I'm working on an animation that pops up a popup screen using DOTween.

```cs
private void OnEnable()
{
  dialogueBoxTransform.localScale = new Vector3(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f);
  dialogueBoxTransform.DOScale(new Vector3(1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f), 0.2f);
  dialogueBoxTransform.DOScale(Vector3.one, 0.1f);
}
```

The problem with the code above is that one of the `DOScale()` methods is ignored.

So I'm trying to implement it using **async-await**.

However, when I use `Task.Run()` it throws an exception because it is not the main thread. So, without using `Task.Run()`, you should solve it.

To do that, I need to create a method that returns a Task, but I don't know how.

```cs
private async void OnEnable()
{
  dialogueBoxTransform.localScale = new Vector3(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f);

  await Test();
      
  dialogueBoxTransform.DOScale(Vector3.one, 0.1f);
}

private Task Test()
{
  dialogueBoxTransform.DOScale(new Vector3(1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f), 0.2f);
  return ???
}
```

I would appreciate any help on what to do.

Comment: Just googled the documentation and found that the `Tween` type has `WaitForXXXX` methods. Never used DOTween, but looks like it could help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @rbcode has mentioned, you should use Sequence. It's a powerful tool that allows you to combine tweens, add callbacks, etc.

In your case it should look like this:

```
dialogueBoxTransform.localScale = new Vector3(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f);

var sequence = DOTween.Sequence();
sequence.Append(dialogueBoxTransform.DOScale(new Vector3(1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f), 0.2f));
sequence.Append(dialogueBoxTransform.DOScale(Vector3.one, 0.1f));

sequence.Play();
```

If you want to execute code after the sequence is completed, you can add a callback before calling `Play`:

```
sequence.AppendCallback(() => {
   //Insert your logic here.
});

sequence.Play();
```

Answer (score 3):

And as option you can use https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask#external-assets for DoTween async. It's free and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
async Task<bool> Test()
{
    bool b = await dialogueBoxTransform.DOScale(new Vector3(1.2f, 1.2f, 
1.2f), 0.2f).AsyncWaitForCompletion();
}
```

and by the way you just can try .OnComplete(delegate{[Your method with/without parameters]}); and no need to use async ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [sequence feature](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php#creatingSequence) of DOTween. The second `DOScale`-command is ignored, because the first one is not finished yet.